# .Net Core 2 Service fabric build warnings

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, service-fabric-stateful

I am seeing lots of build warnings essentially saying libraries are being restored from .netstandard for service fabric. I am on a Mac, running my SF cluster on Linux vm per the Microsoft docs

```
 warning NU1701: Package 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Services 2.7.198' was restored using '.NETPortable,Version=v0.0,Profile=Profile259, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

My service will deploy to the cluster, but fails to initialize with

```
Error event: SourceId='System.Hosting', 
Property='CodePackageActivation:Code:EntryPoint'.
There was an error during CodePackage activation.The service host terminated with exit code:34304
```

This post seems to suggest that it is because the vm hosting my cluster is linux, which can't run .net 4.6 libraries, it is erring out.

Is it fair to assume that this is because of the .net standard libaries attempting to run on linux? A bit lost at this time. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Is it possible to run stateful .netcore services on the linux vm?

It seems to be suggested all over the docs, but I haven't seen a full guide for it on linux. All of the Microsoft docs lead to java based services being deployed. I found some yeoman templates for .net core service fabric services, but in another article so no indication these run on linux. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: I wrote an answer here that might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48170445/deploy-a-c-sharp-stateful-service-fabric-application-from-visual-studio-to-linux